# 2-D cache blocking Optimization

Tags: caching, optimization, architecture, blocking

I would like to know if there is a way to optimize the speed of time to implementing this code in C. This part is for initializing the matrix in rowwise. 
For other parts of my whole code are basically calculate current time and Main function, so I guess this initialization is the most time-cost part

Some hint for me is we can use cache blocking. BTW this code is also for imitate the process which CPU scratch data from cache.  I had been figuring it all day but had limited idea. 
Thanks!!

```
void InitializeMatrixRowwise() {
    int i, j;
    double x;
    x = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < DIMENSION; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < DIMENSION; j++) {
            if (i >= j) {
                Matrix[i][j] = x;
                x += 1.0;
            } else 
                Matrix[i][j] = 1.0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That code won't even compile. It's missing a bracket after the else

Comment: I just upload a part of my whole code, since ,like i said, only this part will cost time.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that the part you did upload isn't valid code